# A counting problem about round tables and restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

Six namecards are at the six seats at a round table. The six people whose names are on the cards sit at the table without looking at the cards. How many ways can they sit so that exactly one of them is sitting at a seat with his or her own name on the namecard.

My approach:

I first thought to fix a position. Let's call the six people A, B, C, D, E, and F. Fixing A to it's position. Then we just need to find the number of ways to arrange the other 5 people without them being at their namecards. After we find that, we can just multiply it by 6, I think.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to find the number of ways to arrange 5 people without them being at their namecards. I've heard of derangements, but I'm not sure how to make them work at a round table.

How do I solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Labeling the seats in a circular arrangement makes the arrangement equivalent to a linear arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

- As N.F. Taussig has remarked. if name cards have been put, it is simply equivalent to seating in a row.
- One of the $6$ persons can occcupy her seat, the other $5$ must be seated in "wrong"  seats. This type of situation is called a [partial derangement](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialDerangement.html)
- You can study [derangements](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html) and partial derangements. At a basic level, derangements can be obtained using inclusion-exclusion, but here I'll give the shortcut that uses the nearest integer $nint(n!/e)$ for a derangement of $n$ objects

Thus the answer will be $6\times nint(5!/e) = 264$